# Citrix XenApp alternative?

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix

I have one Windows application that I need to use when I travel. I have a Chromebook and wouldn't mind getting a tablet. It seems like a waste and a hassle to get a full laptop just for that one application. While looking for solutions, I came across Citrix Receiver and XenApp. It seems to do the trick, however I don't have a server and don't know how complicated it would be.

The reason I'm not using Remote Desktop or the like is because it's very important that it works and if something happens that requires me to have physical access to my home PC to fix, I could be without the app for days/weeks.

Are there any hosted solutions for this, so that I don't need my own server? Or does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have a windows app you'd like to be able to access remotely from a tablet / chromebook, but don't want to use Remote Desktop (rdp) due to stability concerns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use to [Applidis, Systancia](http://www.systancia.com/).

This solution permits to publish your application through a client or webacess onto your tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix XenApp is absolute overkill and very likely much too expensive. Use RDP or some other desktop access/sharing product.

Answer (score 0):

I am a certified XenApp 6.5 Admin.

Basically, you are going to need an entire Windows Domain in order to get XenApp running.
This means paying for Window Server licensing fees, buying a huge server with an i7 and loads of memory, paying for Citrix XenApp licenses, etc.
This is the reason that it will be overkill for a single user with a single application.

XenApp is not for you.

Now, your next bet would be to see if your Chromebook uses an x86 processor (not an ARM) processor.
-If your Chromebook uses an ARM processor... sell it and or get a laptop/tablet with Windows that will run your application.

If your Chromebook happens to use an x86 processor AND your program works at Platinum level under WINE (https://www.winehq.org/) (You can find out how well it works searching in the WINE AppDB, https://appdb.winehq.org/), then you might be able to make it work by installing Ubuntu on your Chromebook, then installing WINE, and then installing your program.

If you are unable/uncomfortable installing Ubuntu on your Chromebook and or your program does not run at Platinum level using WINE: Sell your Chromebook and or get a Windows laptop to run your program.

TL;DR:

If your Chromebook is x86 AND you can install Ubuntu AND your program runs at Platinum level using WINE, then install Ubuntu, install WINE, install your program.

If not, then get a Windows laptop/tablet.